# How to get back to previous page after HTML form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this HTML code which contains two HTML forms and two buttons: 
One for submit and one for cancel (basically get back to the previous page). What I would like to do is after I click the SUBMIT button and submit my forms do the same as the cancel button (get back to the previous page).
The problem is that I can't specify what page I want it to go back since this page will be used in many pages so it will be dynamic.

```
<div data-role="page" id="customer" data="Page" data-expired="true" data-theme="c">

    <div data-role="content" data="customers" data-key="id" data-params="item:itemid">

        <div align="left">
            <h3 style="margin:0px">Customer Profile</h3>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="popup-hrule">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-collapsed-icon="false" data-theme="a">
                <h3>Customer</h3>
                <form id="submit-edit-customer" method="post" data-formaction="process">


                            <label for="customer_name">Customer</label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" data-item=":customer_name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <label for="name">Primary Contact</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="no valid name"
                                   data-item=":name">
                        </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="false" data-theme="a">
                <h3>Billing</h3>
                <form id="submit-edit-customer" method="post" data-formaction="process">


                            <label for="customer_name">Customer</label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" data-item=":customer_name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <label for="name">Primary Contact</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                                   data-item=":name">
                        </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <a id="createeditcancel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="#" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a id="submit-edit-customer-btn" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a">Save</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, is there any easy way to do this without writing a lot of javascript code in the onclick event?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the previous page's url to the href in your Cancel and Save <a> tags? href = "thelastpage.html" should work.

Comment: Is this for jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know I could do this but I tried it and it worked!
I added:  `data-rel="back"` to the submit button.

Like this:

```
<a id="submit-edit-customer-btn" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy all you have to do is change the href to the url of previous page:

```
<a id="createeditcancel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="YOUR_URL_HERE" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
```

Edit: if your submit is using php to save the info just add

```
header("Location: last_page.html");
```

Since its dynamic you can just get the back URL from the same place as the rest of your info and do:

```
header("Location:" + URL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry but I was talking about the Submit button, I was saying that after I submit the form I would like to get back to the previous page. The Cancel button that I have in my form is working just fine by going back to the previous page.

Comment: Hello Saul, My answer bellow is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Leo for your answer but I just found the answer myself. Thank you anyway.

Comment: ok, please post your answer and mark it as correct, or vote for one of the answers that works for you, in case another user come to this question he actually find an answer...

Answer (score 0):

For redirect to other page in JavaScript you can use

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

add to button onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';"

where u handle your form?php file?

other option in php

```
    if (isset($_POST['submitform']))
    {   
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
</script>      
    <?php
    }
```

or in form

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<script>
    function myFunction() {
 location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `document.referrer`:

```js
var cancel = function() {
  window.location.href = document.referrer;
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel()" />
```

With `history`:

```js
var cancel1 = function() {
  history.back();
};
var cancel2 = function() {
  history.go(-1);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel1()" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel2()" />
```

Comment: I haven't seen the document.referer solution yet. Quick and dirty, I love it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

on the action page or your controller try adding this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.location = 'url' // the path to your homepage
});
```